# Term by term integration.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

How do I go about proving this statement?

If $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k(x)$$is a series of nonnegative measurable functions and $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\int_Ef_k(x)dx\right)$$ converges, then $$\sum_
{k=1}^\infty f_k(x)$$ converges almost everywhere and $$\int_E\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k(x)\right)dx=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\int_E f_k(x)dx\right)$$

Comment: When asking questions here it is important to describe some of your effort in attacking the problem.  I'll a partial answer and leave something for you to finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have for each $x \in E$ the convergence of partial sums as $n \to \infty$ according to

$$\sum_{k=1}^n f_k(x) \uparrow \sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k(x) \leqslant +\infty$$

> Why is it true that the sequence of partial sums is non-decreasing and
>   must always converge to a possibly extended nonnegative real number?

By the monotone convergence theorem,

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_E f_k(x) \, dx = \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \int_E f_k(x) \, dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_E \sum_{k=1}^nf_k(x) \, dx = \int_E \sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k(x)\, dx$$

We are given that the series on the LHS converges, and it follows that

$$\int_E \sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k(x)\, dx < +\infty$$

> What does this tell you about $ \sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k(x)$?